# Emacs 24: is there a way to use cc-mode's indentation?

Tags: css, emacs, cc-mode

I'm using Emacs 24, and although I'm not a very experienced Emacs Lisper, I've gotten things to work reasonably well.  That said, I have no idea how to go about getting the standard css-mode to use cc-mode's indentation.  I like the way cc-mode knows how to indent after an opening brace and unindent when it encounters a closing brace on a new line.

edit: I'm one of those horrible people who uses Allman-style braces, so I'll show you what I have so far.  When I press , my cursor ends up at the box character:

```
@media print                                                                    
{
    #table-of-contents                                                          
    {
        display: none
    }
□
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
@media print                                                                    
{
    #table-of-contents                                                          
    {
        display: none
    }
    □
```

Answer (score 0):

CC mode is probably overkill for CSS, but see this example for deriving from it for a new language:

http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/derived-mode-ex.el

One thing that might come up is the unindenting of labels or class visibility specifiers (things followed by ':', since that is common in CSS) in CC mode.  Worth a shot, though!

Comment: Although, I have to mention that I get the indentation you asked for in the default css-mode in Emacs 24.3.  So I'm not sure what exactly is lacking in the built-in css-mode.

Comment: Some Googling prior to asking this question suggested that I should be getting that behavior as default, but it doesn't seem to be the case.  I'll edit my original post to reflect what's going on more explicitly.